# How do I install git/git-svn on RHEL5 with a custom perl install?

Tags: rhel5, git, redhat, epel

I've had nothing but trouble trying to install Git on RHEL5.  First I tried from source, but ran into several issues with installing the docs.  There appeared to be missing libs and such for parsing xml that I couldn't figure out how to get installed and recognized.  Then I tried using the EPEL yum repository and was able to install git and its docs but now git-svn is not working.  It complains about not finding the perl modules Git.pm and SVN/Core.pm.  When I set the GITPERLLIB environment variable to the location of those libs it seg faults.

Some background:  RHEL5 came with perl 5.8.8, but we wanted to use 5.10 so I installed that from source (to a custom location).  Someone then symlinked the system perl binary to this newer version of Perl to make sure nobody uses the wrong version.  Each developer also has their own build of Perl.

So I'm wondering what's the best way to install Git on this system and have both the docs and git-svn working correctly for each user.  Unfortunately I'm a developer and not as good with system administration so take it easy on me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/ it is working for me !!

Comment: Thanks for the resource, but can you elaborate?  Are you using RHEL5 with a custom built perl and do git-svn and the git man pages work for you?

Comment: #  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 / i386:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 / x86_64:

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS//rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

then yum update and yum install git svn after that you can

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your problem lies with symlinking system perl to your custom installation. Then perl modules to add svn support to git were installed for wrong perl installation. A possible hotfix would be to find where exactly were Git.pm and SVN/Core.pm installed. `locate Git.pm` and `locate Core.pm` should do the trick. Then copy found files to the other perl installation and you should be done.

Note however that mixing your custom perl into system will probably cause you a lot of headaches down the way...Keeping it out of PATH is much safer way.